# Python find n number of equidistant values between min and max in a list or array

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list of float values arranged in ascending order. I want to find m equi distant values and their index in that list.

```
list = [2,3,3.2,3.5,4.1, 6.2, 7.3, 8.4, 9.5, 10.6, 12.1, 14.2, 16.3, 18.4, 20]
```

I want to find 4 equi distant values between min and max in the above list.  Also, I want to find their index position.

```
min = 2
max = 20    
dif = 20-2 = 18    
find_val = [2+1*(18/5), 2+2*(18/5), 2+3*(18/5), 2+4*(18/5)]
find_val = [5.6,         9.2,         12.8,          16.4]
```

I want to find the values closest to in `find_val`. Also, I want to know their index position.

I am expecting following output:

```
result_list = [6.2,   9.5,   12.1,  16.3]
result_idx = [5, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: could you please provide the expected output and actual output if applicable

Comment: Question is updated. Thanks

Comment: You can iterate over the values keeping track of the previous one, when you reach or surpass one of the `find_val` check if the distance is greater between the previous value and the find_val or the current value and the find_val and yield the appopriate value and its index.

Comment: Is there a better approach than what I did above requiring multiple lines of code? I feel, my approach looks like a manual approach, not algorithmic.

Comment: Your approach seems to be assuming that the input consists of equally spaced numbers. Is this known to be the case? Could the input list be `[1,2,3,4,10000000000]`? Should the numbers be equidistant, or are their indexes the ones that should be equidistant?

Comment: I updated my question. They are not equidistant.

Comment: @Msquare where is the 5 coming from?

Comment: It is index of main `list`

Answer (score 1):

So here is a function to do it which excludes the min and max in the list:

```
def find_n_equidistant(n, in_list):
    min_n = min(in_list)
    max_n = max_n(in_list)
    find_vals = [min_n+x*((max_n - min_n)/(n+1)) for x in range(1,n+1)]
    out_indexes = [] # the indexes of the closest elements
    for value in find_vals:
        out_indexes.append(min(map(lambda x: [x[0], abs(value-x[1])], enumerate(in_list)), key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
    return [in_list[index] for index in out_indexes], out_indexes
```

The main meat of this function is `min(map(lambda x: [x[0], abs(value-x[1])], indexed_list), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]`

We map to transform each element of the indexed list into an absolute difference between it and the value we are trying to find. Then we find the minimum of the list (the closest element.) Since we attached the index to each element (based on where it is in the main list) we can then lookup the actual value in the main list (since it was just transformed with the map.) That is what is happening when we return at the end. We can also directly return the out indexes.

Use the function like this:

```
values, indexes = find_n_equidistant(4, in_list) # reminder that its bad practice to name lists `list` because it causes issues with the default function list()
```